how to find urdf of mobile robots used in industries?
i need to find the urdf of mobile robots/platforms used in industries. where can I find them? I have visited the official websites of leading manufacturers of AMRs , but couldn't find the urdf.
any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

That data is likely to be kept private, similar to part files, pcb drawings, and the like, as to protect the manufactures' property. You are unlikely to find the urdf file for most industrial robots, unless they have open-sources some of their software for us to use.
Depending on your goal, there may be other methods / sources for you. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

I want to try to load a industrial mobile robot into gazebo , I couldn't find the urdf for mobile robots but was able to find for manipulators.

If you are just looking to simulate "an" industrial mobile robot, creating a box with wheels would do for most applications. You can then integrate a manipulator into that custom urdf using the sources you found. The urdf file is mostly for visualization only, the useful parts (static links to sensors & wheels) would have to be customized for your simulation regardless.
